# Ati 5470 problem with compiz effects. After reboot blackened parts of screen(bottom and right)

Tags: 10.04

Im using 10.04 version of Ubuntu distro. I was planning to completely migrate from other OS to Ubuntu, but a problem has occured. After installing ubuntu i was happy with it since new video card drivers from Ati has been realesed and it worked quite well for a week. All effects just worked fine. But today after restart I've logged and some strange things happened. The Bottom and Right parts of the screen was completely blackened. Looked like resolution change.After that ive looked into my aticcc for display settings it was the same 1366x768 with a look of like ~1200x600. After that searched the forums and found that if i change my effects to none in appearance menu it should back to normal . And yes it worked. But I want my effects  with normal screen resolution back. Note that everything worked fine just before this morning.

xorg.conf file was also with that resolution i need

Comment: Solved . Just need to mark auto detect function at compiz general menu and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Gedas answered the question himself (but in a comment):

> You just need to enable the auto detect function in compiz general menu.